# Python Import file from sibling folder

Tags: python, import

I was trying to import a function from a sibling folder and i could, i look for documentation and didnt found something useful, can you help me please?

I have a folder named fold1, inside i have fold2 and fold3, inside fold2 i have filetoimport.py, it has:

```
def fntest(a, b):
    return print(a+b)
```

And i want to import that function from inside fold3 file main.py, there i have

```
from fold2 import filetoimport

filetoimport.fntest(2,2)
```

Then i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fold3/main.py", line 1, in <module>
fold1 import filetoimport
ImportError: No module named 'fold1'
```

Hope you can help me :)

I also tried

```
from fold1.fold2 import filetoimport
```

But it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the parent folder as a path the program can check inside for more modules. I had some luck with this

```
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('..'))
   
    from fold2 import filetoimport
    filetoimport.fntest(2,2)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fold3/main.py", line 1, in <module>    
    from fold1.fold2.filetoimport import fntest
ImportError: No module named 'fold1'

I still can't import it :(

Comment: I was reading the problem wrong I though the folders where nested not adjacent inside fold1. With this new edit you should be able to import a def from fold2 into a main.py located in fold3.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this should work

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(1,os.popen('pwd').read().replace('3\n','2'))

import filetoimport

filetoimport.fntest(2,2)
```

you just need to add the target folder to the python runtime path

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fold3/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import filetoimport
ImportError: No module named 'filetoimport'

Also it doesnt recognize pwd as valid command inside the python file :(

Comment: what kind of operating system are you using, linux or windows

Comment: I'm using windows

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood, your folder structure is as below

```
fold1
    fold2
        -- filetoimport.py
    fold3 
        -- main.py
```

It seems that your are executing the **main.py** file from terminal (by opening **fold1** path) as

```
python3 fold3/main.py
```

[image]

Instead you should execute the command as

```
python3 -m fold3.main
```

[image]

Since the argument is a module name, you must not give a file extension (.py)

On the other hand if you open **fold1** as a project in IDE like pycharm or intellij idea and execute **main.py** via IDE itself, it wont give you an error.

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer help you @Ranniex ?